# click on a hyperlink,app need to move on a another view in Xcode

Tags: html, xcode

I am displaying HTML file in a web view.When User clicks on a hyper link, i want to move on another view in same app.How can I do this??

" href = "new view controller""

What is the URL of "new view controller"??

How to find it??

thanks.

Comment: have no idea what to use...:(

Answer (score 0):

There is no address to use for view controller, but you can add events to capture the click of anchors.

this is an example:

in HTML file:

```
<a href="#HELLO">Hello World</a>
```

in your .m file (xCode):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

NSURL * URL = [request URL];

if ([URL rangeOfString:@"#HELLO"].location != NSNotFound) {
// Do whatever you want here.
}

return YES;
}
```

the shouldStartLoadWithRequest activates every time the location of the webview is changed,
when you click on the anchor, the location will be for example: file.html#HELLO

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. If you are creating the html, then you should know what links look like. If so, it is a simple matter of checking the link before loading the webview. You should set the webview's delegate to self and then do something like:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", request.URL];
if([urlString isEqualToString:@"http://www.myCustomHyperLink"])
{
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNextViewController];
 return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

In the example above, if the url is the url you need to open the next view, the navigation controller pushes the next view controller and returns NO so that the webview does not get reloaded. Else the webview reloads the page.

You can change the if statement to whatever suits your needs.

I use this in an application like this:

I have multiple links in a view. So, if the link is one of my own, I open it in a second view controller.Else, I open Safari. This is because I don't want to turn my application into a browser.
So I have something like:

```
if([urlString rangeOfString:@"www.myDomain.com"].location == NSNotFound)
{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.Url];
}
else 
...push the next view controller how I showed you above.
```